# Altium 23.4 default font

Tags: altium

I'm trying to use Altium 23.4 and wondering how I can change the default font (Times New Roman) ?
I tried by changing each item in options menu but when I import new lib (for example) some text are still with default font...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Fonts are selected in Preferences, Schematic (or PCB Editor), Defaults; not options. Beware of using fonts other than the default fonts as Altium's built in PDF printer may mangle the text by adding spaces in the text where you don't want them (makes the document unsearchable). Perhaps they have fixed this in V23.  A 3rd party PDF printer driver solves this issue.

Comment: I have yet to find a nice looking font for AD ... and I wish it could be embedded into the SchDocs.

Answer (score 1):

## You can’t.

---

[Altium documentation — “Schematic pin customization”](https://techdocs.altium.com/en/display/ADOH/Schematic+Pin+Customization):

> Use the `Use local font setting` option to change from following the default font, to an overriding, customized font.
>
> With this option disabled (default), the font used for the pin *Name* and *Designator* will be:
>
> - **Schematic Library Document** –  `Times New Roman, 10pt, Regular`. This is fixed. **There is no ability to change the default font for a library document.**

---

[Altium documentation — “Creating a schematic symbol in Altium Designer (version 23)”](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/creating-schematic-symbol?version=23):

> The default system font for a schematic library document is `Times New Roman, 10pt, Regular`. **This is fixed and cannot be changed.** When a library component is placed on a schematic sheet, this same default font is applied but is not fixed and can be changed as required. Keep in mind that the system font used for a schematic sheet applies to other objects as well, including Power Ports, Ports, and the X, Y region markers in the schematic sheet border.